# Is $x^3\sin(1/x^3)$ a uniform continuous function on $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the function is uniformly continuous, because it can be continuously extended to a function on the closed interval $[0,1]$, since
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x^3\sin\frac{1}{x^3}=0
$$
The function on $[0,1]$
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=0$}\\[6px]
x^3\sin\dfrac{1}{x^3} & \text{if $0<x\le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous on a closed and bounded interval, so it is uniformly continuous and hence any restriction thereof is also uniformly continuous.

---

Note that the derivative of your function is
$$
3x^2\sin\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{3}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x^3}
$$
so the derivative is not bounded on $(0,1)$. However, boundedness of the derivative is a sufficient condition for a function to be Lipschitzian, which in turn is stronger than uniform continuity.